# path-problems with deploying vue CLI-app in hosting environment

Tags: vue.js, npm, deployment, path, shared-hosting

i build an app with **"npm run build"**. dist-folder created successfully. Then i uploaded the dist folder and index.html to the right path on my hosting server (**m.myapp2go/vueapp/dist**) with a ftp-client. Now there is a path-problem! In the get-request ***"/vueapp/dist"*** is missing. If i call the app with **http://m.myapp2go.de/vueapp/** the following error occurs in console.

[image]

Installation on server:

[image]

Do i have to set the path to deployment-server before build? And when, where can i do this? THX

Comment: the `npm run build` runs the `build` command, you can find it in your `package.json`. It will likely point towards some `vue-cli` call. Check for options there.

Comment: where can i put the path for a correct distribution of the app?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Perhaps a good instruction for others, with the same problem. It's a very weird topic, and the documentation for deploying to a hosted server is very inadequate in the web.

If you want to deploy e.g. to:

> m.myapp2go.de/vueapp/

you have to set the **vue CLI configuration** in the **vue ui** as follows:

[image]

Then run

> npm run build

and then copy the **index.html** to your **root-folder** on the server and your **dist-folder** to your **dist-folder** on server.

And, voilà, the test app is running perfect on the hosted server!

[image]

Comment: i didnt even know there was a UI for the Vue CLI, i guess the 'Basis-URL' setting is directly related to https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath .

Comment: @ Flame . Yes, that's correct. It is the **publicPath** in **vue.config.js**.